# Jaxb unmarshall without using getters/setters while expected to

Tags: java, jaxb

I got surprised from Jaxb while using annotations in the following code:

```
@XmlRootElement()
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Competences {
    @XmlElement(name = "lv") private List<Lv> lvs;

    public List<Lv> getLvs() {
        return null;
    }

    public void setLvs(List<Lv> lvs) {
        this.lvs = lvs;
    }
}
```

I expect the unmarshall result to be empty, but he was fill as if he was using directly the field (despite the field is private).

**Question**

- How can Jaxb access private attributes ?
- How am I supposed make him using getters/setters (while keeping a FIELD access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can Jaxb access private attributes ?

Via reflection. You (most of the time) can do `Field.setAccessible(true)` and access the field even if it is private.

> How am I supposed make him using getters/setters (while keeping a FIELD access)

This is a strange question. The `@XmlAccessorType` is exactly about specifying how do you want to access properties of the mapped classes. Why do you want to specify `FIELD` access but actually use `PROPERTY` access?

Comment: Actually, it's just about me finding elegant to put the annotation on the attributes rather than on getters. So I make my self believe that he can't access them without accessors.